# Rounding numbers using geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a plot using pivot_longer and geom_col, but the percents I get show something like 8 decimal places when I try to display them over each bar using geom_text...how can I get them rounded to 1 or 2 places?

```
d %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('a_')) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarize(percent = mean(value == 1)) %>% 
  ggplot() + aes(name, percent) + 
  geom_col(fill = "blue", color = "black") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent)) +
  ggtitle("Title")
```

Comment: try `geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(percent)))`. You can set the `accuracy` argument to control how many digits to show.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect...is there an argument that gets rid of the % sign (seems like the default...)

Comment: Yep you can set the `suffix` argument to `""`. You can also use `scales::number(percent)` if you prefer, but it doesn't do the `* 100` operation you might want for percentages.

Comment: @teunbrand thanks!